# How to extract complete text occuring inside tags based on a keyword?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a log file which has content in this format:

<webdoc>

details
of
customers in multiple lines

</webdoc>

**ORA-01461:** can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Now what I want to do is that run a script at the end of the day and look for the keyword **ORA-01461** , and if it occurs, extract the contents from inside of  customer tag occuring just before the keyword and store in a text file.

Comment: What research did you do? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please note that it's impossible to parse xml with regex - prefer xml aware tools. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I recommend [questions checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Please read [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - please put the input in a code block. So you want to output the string `details of customers in multiple lines`?

Comment: yes i want to output the string details of customers in multiple lines

Comment: How does ORA-01161 appear in the file? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some pseudo-code:

```
boolean bCustomer = false;
string l = "";
File fIntermediate;
while not eof{
  l = readline();
  if l = "<customer>" or l="</customer>" or l.contains("ORA-01161") or bCustomer
  then fIntermediate.addAtTheBeginning(l);
  if l = "</customer>"
  then bCustomer = False;
  if l = "<customer>"
  then bCustomer = True;
}
```

The result of that code will have generated an intermediate file, containing the lines with "", "", "ORA..." and the lines between the "customer" tags, in reversed order (hence the `addAtTheBeginning()`).

Then you read that intermediate file, using a similar boolean `bORA-01161_found`, which you put `False` to start. You read the intermediate file. Once you find `ORA-01161` you set the mention boolean to `True` and when you find a line which is neither "", "</customer" nor "ORA-01161" and the mentioned boolean is `True`, you write the content to your resulting textfile.

P.s. first make sure your tagname is correct: first asking for "customer", and while an answer is written accordingly changing it to "webdoc" is a bit weird :-)